# convenient way for data.frame to do matrix computation

Tags: r

Matrix computations such as `A%*%B` require a data.frame to be transformed into a matrix using `as.matrix()`, but this way is cumbersome. Is there a more convenient method to do such things?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is 'disgusting'?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to downvote for using the word "disgusting". English is clearly not the op's native language. I've changed the word now. However, the op should still explain, why they are unhappy with using `as.matrix`.

Comment: Because the data is ofen expressed in the form of data.frame and we can not avoid the situation of doing matrix computations,then we transform every data.frame into matrix,which may be repeated many times.This makes the code a little redundant,and may be the source of some errors if we forget to do such things.

Answer (score 2):

If you objection is just that you have to wrap your data frame in `as.matrix` before using `%*%` then you could make your own binary function that does that wrapping for you

```
`%*df%` <- function(x, y){as.matrix(x) %*% as.matrix(y)}
x <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
x %*df% x
#      a  b
#[1,]  7 15
#[2,] 10 22
```

Comment: Might be interesting to compare `as.matrix` and `data.matrix` for efficiency.